# How to apply pivot in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table which i want to rotate. For example:

From:

```
Id  U-num  Item   Count  Q1   Q2
1   11     item1    10   32   1
1   11     item2    5    7    9
1   11     item3    5    8    0  

2   12     item1    20  132   0
2   12     item2    30   32   0
2   12     item3    20   0    0  

3   4      item1    10  322   0
3   4      item2    10   2    22
3   4      item3    20   32   55
```

to:

```
Id  U-num  Total   Item1-Q1 Item1-Q2 Item2-Q1 Item2-Q2 Item3-Q1 Item3-q2
1   11     20      32          1       7        9        8        0
2   12     70      132       0         32       0        0        0
3   4      40      322       0         2        22       32       55
```

Where **Total** column is **sum of count column for each Id**. For instance Id 1 has count 10,5,5 which goes as 20 in Total column.

I am able to do it by using a cursor on the table1 and forming table2.
But that is not the best way to do it. I checked online and found that I can use Pivot but unable to apply pivot here. Can somebody help me apply pivot here?

Tried several examples on stackoverflow but couldn't figure out how to write query for this.

I am skipping the cursor code here because it was way to big and that is the reason i want to use pivot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very funny:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d04c/3)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (Id int, Unum int, Item varchar(20),  c int,  Q1 int,   Q2 int);
insert into t values 
(1 ,  11     ,'item1',    10 ,  32 ,  1),
(1 ,  11     ,'item2',    5  ,  7  ,  9),
(1 ,  11     ,'item3',    5  ,  8  ,  0),  
(2 ,  12     ,'item1',    20 , 132 ,  0),
(2 ,  12     ,'item2',    30 ,  32 ,  0),
(2 ,  12     ,'item3',    20 ,  0  ,  0),  
(3 ,  4      ,'item1',    10 , 322 ,  0),
(3 ,  4      ,'item2',    10 ,  2  ,  22),
(3 ,  4      ,'item3',    20 ,  32 ,  55);
```

**Query 1**:

```
;with cte as (
  select Id, Unum, item + '-Q1' as Q, Q1 as v, 
         sum(c) over ( partition by Id) as T from t 
  union all
  select Id, Unum, item + '-Q2' as Q, Q2 as v, 
         sum(c) over ( partition by Id ) as T from t )  
SELECT Id, Unum, T, [Item1-Q1], [Item1-Q2], 
                    [Item2-Q1], [Item2-Q2], 
                    [Item3-Q1], [Item3-q2]
FROM CTE
PIVOT
(
sum (v)
FOR Q IN
( [Item1-Q1], [Item1-Q2], 
  [Item2-Q1], [Item2-Q2], 
  [Item3-Q1], [Item3-q2] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d04c/3/0)**:

```
| Id | Unum |  T | Item1-Q1 | Item1-Q2 | Item2-Q1 | Item2-Q2 | Item3-Q1 | Item3-q2 |
|----|------|----|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|  1 |   11 | 20 |       32 |        1 |        7 |        9 |        8 |        0 |
|  2 |   12 | 70 |      132 |        0 |       32 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|  3 |    4 | 40 |      322 |        0 |        2 |       22 |       32 |       55 |
```

Answer (score 1):

we can achieve the same result set using CROSS APPLY and PIVOT

```
declare  @t table  (Id int, Unum int, Item varchar(20),  c int,  Q1 int,   Q2 int);
insert into @t values 
(1 ,  11     ,'item1',    10 ,  32 ,  1),
(1 ,  11     ,'item2',    5  ,  7  ,  9),
(1 ,  11     ,'item3',    5  ,  8  ,  0),  
(2 ,  12     ,'item1',    20 , 132 ,  0),
(2 ,  12     ,'item2',    30 ,  32 ,  0),
(2 ,  12     ,'item3',    20 ,  0  ,  0),  
(3 ,  4      ,'item1',    10 , 322 ,  0),
(3 ,  4      ,'item2',    10 ,  2  ,  22),
(3 ,  4      ,'item3',    20 ,  32 ,  55);
select * from (
select ID,Unum,Item +'-'+col As K,SUM(C) over ( partition by Id)/2 as T,val from @t
CROSS APPLY (values ('Q1',Q1),('Q2',Q2))CS(col,val))A
PIVOT(SUM(Val) FOR K IN ([Item1-Q1], [Item1-Q2], 
  [Item2-Q1], [Item2-Q2], 
  [Item3-Q1], [Item3-Q2]))HH
```